# How can I get my video card driver to install?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

I had Windows XP which installed the video drivers for my Intel (R) 865G graphics chip accelerated VGA BIOS drivers.

Now however I have Windows 7 installed but it doesn't install the video card. The video card is built-in but I can't use it since it's not installed.

How can I get the driver to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There are no official Windows 7 drivers for that chip](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&ProdId=1044&DwnldID=18576&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Desktop%20graphics%20controllers&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%2082865G%20Graphics%20and%20Memory%20Controller%20Hub%20%28GMCH%29&lang=eng), so I guess it's just picking it up as "Standard VGA Graphics Adaptor"

[This thread post](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Operating-systems-and/Win-7-Support-for-Intel-865G-Graphics-HP-D530-SFF/m-p/173142/message-uid/173142/highlight/true#U173142) covers an alternative solution, which seems to involve a tweaked version of the Vista drivers but it's definitely a buyer-beware situation. With Windows 7-compatible graphics cards available for as little as £20 it's not a solution I'd personally risk.